# How to get the selected values in primeng multiselect?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms

How to get the selected option label and value in primeng multiselect (p-multiselect). Am using reactive form.

Answer (score 1):

In html

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" formControlName="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>
```

In component

You can get value like this

```
this.your_form.controls['selectedCities'].value
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>`

You can get value like this

`this.selectedCities`

Comment: ngModal is template forms and the question is regarding reactive forms. formControlName and FormGroups etc